# How to get list of items from DynamoDB with HashKey while using HashKey+RangeKey combination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have my table with UserId(hashkey)+id(Rangekey). they are only together unique as expected.

```
  [DynamoDBTable("Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [DynamoDBHashKey]

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBRangeKey]

        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

now I want to get all the table items for a UserId. I tried as below using xamarin sdk loadasync function with parameter of an existing UserId.

```
          var client = new 
Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWS.DynamoDBhelper.Credentials, 
    Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
                        Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext context = new 
    Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext(client);
                        Items= await context.LoadAsync<List<Item>>("14354365");
```

But i get exception as below, it looks like It expects not list because it assumes there should be table with table with list. 
How can I achieve this? 
There is also QueryAsync function but I am not sure what is the difference between LoadAsync.

```
        ex = {System.InvalidOperationException: Must have one hash key defined
 for the table List`1
          at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext.MakeKey (System.Object 
    hashKey, System.Object rangeKey,
     Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.ItemStorageConfig storageConfig, Amaz...
```

Comment: You're trying to retrieve correct? If you are you should be using the defined "scan" and "query" methods (Lines +225). Load is for importing... https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-xamarin/blob/master/AWS.XamarinSDK/AWSSDK_WP8/Amazon.DynamoDBv2/DataModel/IDynamoDBContext.Async.cs

Comment: I think that it should be as described here. I figured out later. Correct function looks FromQueryAsync with QueryFilter. But I wonder in which cases we should use LoadAsync function. There is only example when there is hashkey defined. It looks like that it doesnt support composite hash+range key. But I wonderf why?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/dynamodb-integration-objectpersistencemodel.html

Comment: actually in the link FromQueryAsync requires an index to be created. I am curious if it is not possible without creating an index.

Comment: did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
var client = new Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient(
   AWS.DynamoDBhelper.Credentials, 
   Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1
 );
Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext context = new 
    Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext(client);

Items= await context.LoadAsync<List<Item>>("14354365");`
```

Should read:

```
var client = new Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient(
   AWS.DynamoDBhelper.Credentials, 
   Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1
 );
Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext context = new 
    Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBContext(client);    

items= await context.QueryAsync<Item>("14354365").GetRemainingAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use LoadAsync to get an object by both its hash + range key.

The .NET library has this:

```
public Task<T> LoadAsync<T>(
    object hashKey, 
    object rangeKey, 
    DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

Use Load when the method requires only the primary key of the item you want to retrieve.